# Auto focus on input filed in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive for auto focus on text box

```
 (function () {
'use strict';
 angular.module('commonModule').directive('srFocuson',function(){ 
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    console.log('value=', value);
                   element[0].focus();
                    scope[attrs.focusMe] = false;

                }
            });
        }
    };
});

})();
```

And now i want to bind that directive to my text box.I have tried to bind to input field but its not working.

```
 <input placeholder="SR ID, SSN/ITIN, or School ID" sr-focuson="focusMe" type="text"        
  id="form_ID" name="searchId" autofocus
            data-ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.searchId"
            maxlength="20" class="form-control">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/A39duXhGvCedAaVuB3uQ?p=preview

Comment: missing sr-focuson in your html?

Comment: ok:) and now attrs.focusMe should be attrs.srFocuson ...

Comment: Included but still not working

Comment: please create a fiddle or plunkr, it will help us to help you.

Comment: Here's the link http://plnkr.co/edit/A39duXhGvCedAaVuB3uQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I made working fiddle with your idea. http://jsfiddle.net/fLaAG/

It's sort of unclear where you would be updating scope.focusMe so I made an explicit button that would set that value to true.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="Focus()" type="button">Focus</button>
...
$scope.Focus = function() {
    $scope.focusMe = true;
};
```

Also I'm setting up an isolate scope, so I can just watch string I give it.

```
scope: {
    focusMe: '=focusOn'
},
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using built-in angular functionality, dug out from the murky depths of the angular docs. Notice how the "link" attribute can be split into "pre" and "post", for pre-link and post-link functions.

[Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB)

```js
// this is the directive you add to any element you want to highlight after creation
Guest.directive('autoFocus', function() {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function preLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('prelink called');
                // this fails since the element hasn't rendered
                //element[0].focus();
            },
            post: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('postlink called');
                // this succeeds since the element has been rendered
                element[0].focus();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```
<input value="hello" />
<!-- this input automatically gets focus on creation -->
<input value="world" auto-focus />
```

[Full AngularJS Directive Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: I would like to add a ; after "return {}" for the code to pass jslint, but StackOverflow doesn't allow me to do 1 letter edits =/

Comment: added the semicolon. @hoeni, it seems to be working on my firefox